# How to sign a contract without web3js?

Tags: transactions, ethereum, web3js

I want to sign and user "sendSignTransaction" method with web3js but gives me error meaning of error is by node provider doesnt support that function so how to handle this or are there any free nodes that I can use instead of alchemy or infura that supports what I wanted to do.

Tryed to sign a transaction with webjs but didnt work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use infura or alchemy nodes for intraction with etherem blockchain and you can use web3.js for interacting with Ethereum nodes.You can also setup and use your local node.

Here are some general steps for interacting and sending a simple transfer transaction.

```
const Web3 = require('web3'); //import web3

// Connect to an Ethereum node using Infura (replace with your own API key)
const web3 = new Web3('https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/your-infura-api-key');

// You can also set the provider using a local Ethereum node
// const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

const fromAddress = 'YourAddress';
const privateKey = 'YourPrivateKey';

const rawTransaction = {
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)),
  gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000), // Standard gas limit for a simple transfer transaction
  to: 'RecipientAddress',
  value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')), // Amount to send
  data: '0x', // Optional data field for contract transactions
};

const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey);

const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);

console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
```

This code demonstrate a simple transaction which send "0.1" ether from your address to recipient address using sendSignedTransaction method.